# Formula Identification for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some Excel help. I work for a lending company and we have to request certain documents depending on the program that the borrower is eligible for. So I want a program that takes a few inputs from a drop down to specify the program type and then an output that states which documents I need to request. Something like this:

If this is selected and this is selected and this is selected then output these documents.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1491399/edit) to provide the example? You can upload images to http://imgur.com and link to them. Someone with enough reputation will likely embed them for you. It would also be useful to know what you have tried so far

Comment: I would likely use a data validation and drop down boxes to select the inputs (to insure consistency in the text), and then use Lookups to produce the result, but like Cybermetic.nomad mentions above it is hard to give you much feedback with out see a sample of what we are working with. This doesn't need to be real data, just something to suggest the solution methodology off of.

Comment: What do you expect here?  Are you looking for someone to write code for you for free?  Or some ideas as to how to proceed? You'll need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: The easiest should be dependent drop down ! Please [Edit] your post & share sample data along with line of execution !!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a table format in excel maybe like this:

[image]

Populate the form column with all the different forms you have. Then have attribute columns that would trigger the use/not use of the form. This would be your inputs. In the body of the table put a true/false depending if the attribute requires the form. When this is done, you can filter the attributes and the result is the forms that you need in the form column.

My example would say you require form 1 and 3 if all the attributes are true. Also notice that for form 1, attribute 2 can be either true or false, meaning this attribute is not important to the use of form 1

Hope this gives you some ideas.